# I have a list of Dictionaries each dictionary got a value assigned to a key and I need to grab this value according to other 2 values

Tags: python-3.x, list

This is the list`{'id': 142840, 'posters': [{'aspect_ratio': 0.703125, 'file_path': '/4EFI8IdI7LOm9Q0BTT2FAdPwdeq.jpg', 'height': 2048, 'iso_639_1': 'en', 'vote_average': 5.312, 'vote_count': 1, 'width': 1440}, {'aspect_ratio': 0.70703125, 'file_path': '/2Lgb7oPgqVpJmruRoH7Rs2yJH0n.jpg', 'height': 2048, 'iso_639_1': 'en', 'vote_average': 5.172, 'vote_count': 1, 'width': 1448}, {'aspect_ratio': 0.7068881289692233, 'file_path': '/6mLaG60xEQm6mw0Ga8TDFZsk0R1.jpg', 'height': 2047, 'iso_639_1': None, 'vote_average': 0.0, 'vote_count': 0, 'width': 1447}]}`

I am trying to pick the value of `file_path` if `height`>`width`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It often helps to format a complex data structure to better see how the pieces relate.  In this case it shows that the information you care about (`height`, `width`, and `file_path`) can all be found in the dictionaries inside the `posters` list which is inside a dict we can call `poster_dict`.  With that information we can construct a list of `file_paths` that meet the specified `height` and `width` relationship.

Example:

```
poster_dict = {
    "id": 142840,
    "posters": [
        {
            "aspect_ratio": 0.703125,
            "file_path": "/4EFI8IdI7LOm9Q0BTT2FAdPwdeq.jpg",
            "height": 2048,
            "iso_639_1": "en",
            "vote_average": 5.312,
            "vote_count": 1,
            "width": 1440,
        },
        {
            "aspect_ratio": 0.70703125,
            "file_path": "/2Lgb7oPgqVpJmruRoH7Rs2yJH0n.jpg",
            "height": 2048,
            "iso_639_1": "en",
            "vote_average": 5.172,
            "vote_count": 1,
            "width": 1448,
        },
        {
            "aspect_ratio": 0.7068881289692233,
            "file_path": "/6mLaG60xEQm6mw0Ga8TDFZsk0R1.jpg",
            "height": 2047,
            "iso_639_1": None,
            "vote_average": 0.0,
            "vote_count": 0,
            "width": 1447,
        },
    ],
}

file_path_list = [
    one_poster["file_path"]
    for one_poster in poster_dict["posters"]
    if one_poster["height"] > one_poster["width"]
]

print(file_path_list)
```

Output:

```
['/4EFI8IdI7LOm9Q0BTT2FAdPwdeq.jpg', '/2Lgb7oPgqVpJmruRoH7Rs2yJH0n.jpg', '/6mLaG60xEQm6mw0Ga8TDFZsk0R1.jpg']
```

Answer (score 1):

As the height and width are only in the last dictionary, you can write the code as shown below :

```
if d['posters'][2]['height'] > d['posters'][2]['width'] :
    return d['posters'][2]['file_path']
```

In case 'height' and 'width' are not in last dictionary, change the value of '[2]'
Hope it's helpful for you.  ;-)